# Can ZnO act as a reducing agent for noble metals like Pd?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, corrosion

Palladium ions (*e.g.*, $\ce{Pd^2+}$) can be reduced to $\ce{Pd}$ by more reactive metals such as zinc. Metal oxides such as $\ce{ZnO}$ are very stable but can its atoms in the oxide structure still be displaced by Pd?
I know the answer is probably "No" but in one of my samples $\ce{ZnO}$ nanoparticles were removed from the solution after I added $\ce{Pd^2+}$ solution to the system and $\ce{Pd}$ nanoparticles were formed. The solvent was methanol. After washing the solution and drying I did XPS and no trace of zinc was observed but saw $\ce{Pd}$ peaks.

Comment: The metals aren’t connected to the Swedish entrepreneur Alfred Nobel but to the English adjective to *nobility: noble.* As for the actual question, I sadly cannot give you an answer.

Comment: Did you measure the size of the nano-particles? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_photoelectron_spectroscopy), at most, the XPS instrument will only probe $\pu{20 nm}$ into a sample. Thus, I wonder, $\ce{Pd}$ has been deposited on $\ce{ZnO}$ surface. "**Palladium Deposition on $\ce{Pt}$ Surface by Reduction of $\ce{Pd^2+}$ Ions with Organic Substances**" has been studied before (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1010314807520).

Answer (score 3):

Zinc chemistry is overwhelmingly that of the +2 oxidation state, it does not go higher. For ZnO to reduce Pd+2, the Zn has to go up from +2 which it cannot. If you are getting reduction of Pd+2, Zn is not responsible.

Comment: Perhaps ZnO is catalyzing the reduction of Pd(II) to Pd(0) with methanol as the reducing agent (oxidized to formaldehyde). I presume the Pd(II) is stable in methanol.